# libGdx unable to find files in android application data directory

Tags: android, file-io, libgdx

I'm trying to access data from my application's data directory.  I'm able to load `default.fnt` file, but then it tells me the associated `default.png` cannot be found. **How can I get the system to recognize the file? Is there something I've setup incorrectly?**

### Exception

```
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 240
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: /data/data/com.iliadonline.client/files/data/gfx/fonts/default.png
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:126)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:125)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:99)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.iliadonline.client.render.Render.loadFonts(Render.java:213)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.iliadonline.client.render.Render.<init>(Render.java:71)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.iliadonline.client.IliadClient.create(IliadClient.java:65)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:322)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: /data/data/com.iliadonline.client/files/data/gfx/fonts/default.png (Internal)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:74)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:224)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    ... 13 more
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.iliadonline.client/files/data/gfx/fonts/default.png
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:72)
07-07 22:22:52.467: E/AndroidRuntime(10785):    ... 15 more
```

---

#### File Permissions

I have checked that the files exist and that they have the right owner/group and even set the permissions to 777 just to test.

[image: Shell Screen Shot]

I've seen several other questions where the problem was with the **assets** folder in the projects, but I'm not using the assets folder. And the code is able to find the .fnt file sitting next to the .png.

---

#### Font Definition Header

> info face="Droid Sans" size=17 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=0
>   stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1 common
>   lineHeight=20 base=18 scaleW=256 scaleH=128 pages=1 packed=0 page id=0
>   file="default.png" chars count=95

---

In case it helps, here is the code I use to get the file handles:

```
FileHandle dataDir = Gdx.files.local("data");

FileHandle gfxDir = dataDir.child("gfx");
if(!gfxDir.isDirectory())
{
    //mkdirs will make all directories, so this includes the "data" dir
    gfxDir.mkdirs();
}

FileHandle spritesDir = gfxDir.child("sprites");
if(!spritesDir.isDirectory())
{
    spritesDir.mkdirs();
}

FileHandle fontsDir = gfxDir.child("fonts");
if(!fontsDir.isDirectory())
{
    fontsDir.mkdirs();
}
```

P.S. The font file and png worked when they were in the assets folder. So I'm assuming they are setup properly.

Comment: Does the exception backtrace from logcat have a "caused by" section after the bit you included?  (I'm wondering if its a file access issue, or if the PNG decoder is running into problems)

Comment: @P.T. I edited with the extended logcat info. `java.io.FileNotFoundException` seems to be the last caused by in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a `FileNotFound` exception from `android.content.res.AssetManager.open`, but the doc for that explicitly states that it [only works with "files bundled as assets"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29).

However, you don't call that directly....

Ah, the [Libgdx BitmapFont constructor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.java#L124) uses `Gdx.files.internal` to load the font texture:

```
public BitmapFont (BitmapFontData data, TextureRegion region, boolean integer) {
        this.region = region == null ? new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(data.imagePath), false)) : region;
        ...
```

(That seems like it might be a bug in Libgdx to just assume the font texture file is "internal", but I'm not sure how they should work around that ...)

I think you can work around this by invoking [the `BitmapFont` constructor that takes an explicit texture file](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#BitmapFont%28com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle,%20com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion,%20boolean%29) in your `loadFonts` method.

Comment: Cool, I'll try it out as soon as I can and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like it was exactly the problem, I edited the code to include a simplified version of the code that's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Posted into the issue tracker. Nightlies now have this fixed.